# What is the intuition behind the decrease in comoving Hubble radius during inflation and then its increase later on?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

We know that the comoving Hubble radius decreases during inflation when the universe is exponentially expanding and then increases during matter and radius domination. What is the reason behind this? I can see it mathematically. However, intuitively it's not so obvious. The universe is expanding during both the eras, accelerating during one while decelerating during the other, but expanding. I would imagine the Hubble radius decreasing during both since if the universe expands light (and causal physics) would have difficult keeping up.

Comment: The reasoning behind the idea that the Hubble radius expands is discussed by Lineweaver & Davis in several articles of theirs, whose titles & contents can all be found with the search terms "Expanding Confusion", & depends on the difference between Special & General relativity:  I'm weak on the latter's math, but you might be able to answer your own question if you can follow it.

Comment: The 1st of Davis & Lineweaver's papers (at https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0310808.pdf) was written 16 years after publication of Guths well-received book titled "The Inflationary Universe", so they were well aware of cosmic inflation., which does seem to be "holding its own" amid the conceptual changes associated with new JWST data.